# How to detect a query param appended to URL using pure React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an injected external widget in my React application that have some links and when clicking in these links a query param is appended to the URL.

Imagine something like this:

- base url: http://localhost:8080/
- url after adding the query param: http://localhost:8080/?shouldOpenModal

Is there any way to detect this appended query param to the URL using React? It's important in here that the page **isn't** fully reloaded, since there's information that cannot be lost and we also **can't use external libraries such as React Router DOM** (which is widely used in similar questions in here).

So far, to append the URL without triggering a reload is using this:

```
if (history.pushState) {
    const newUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + 
                   window.location.host + 
                   window.location.pathname + '?stOpenBenefitsModal';
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to update some app state when update url to re-render your component tree:

```js
....

[state, setState] = useState(window.location)

const navigate = (url)=>{
  window.history.push('','',url);
  setState(window.location)
}


const handlePopState = ()=>{
  setState(window.location)
}

useEffect(()=>{
  // sync back and forward browser button with state
  window.addEvenListener('popstate',handlePopState)
},[])

....

//render something based on state value
```

Comment: This definitely works, I just needed to do some changes to work on my case! Thanks for sharing your thoughts!